# Showing the month on an archive page

Tags: datetime, archives

I've set up an archive page as described in the docs... so my archive page url looks something like this `http://mysite.dev/news/2014/09`.

How do I then make the title display **Archive for September 2014**?

The `{{ month }}` variable is set as 09 and doing this -> `{{ month|date("F") }}` outputs **January** not September.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Figured out a way to do this if anyone who has the same problem.

```
    {% if year is defined and month is defined %}
    {% set archiveDate = year ~ '-' ~ month ~ '-01' %}
    <h2 class='archive-title'>Archive for {{ archiveDate|date('F') }} - {{ year }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
```